# Gradients with loadPixels() in Processing

Tags: java, processing, radial-gradients

Hi everyone – i am trying to draw a radial gradient in the background of my sketch – and I am trying to achieve this by manipulating the pixels like in an example by daniel shiffman – so far so good – it works as it should! BUT – now I want the radial gradient to be red – and the outer parts of the sketch to be black… So just as in the code example below, but inverted!
I tried many things – experimented with the RGB values – inverted the values of the dist(); function – thought of map(); – tried to change the calculations for the pixels – nothing worked out – what am I missing or can somebody explain it to me? I know what the code does – but cant get it inverted… does someone have an idea and can it explain it to me? I am really stuck…

```
void setup() {
 size(1080, 1080);
}

void draw() {
     loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      float d = dist(width/2, height/2, x, y);
      pixels[x+y*width] = color(255,d,255);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
}

void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      float d = dist(width/2, height/2, x, y);
      pixels[x+y*width] = color(255-d, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Here's the trick:

RGB means Red-Green-Blue. They are the three colors which, mixed together, will make up the other colors. The number is how light the color is, so [255, 0, 0] would be a bright red. 255 everywhere would be white, and 0 everywhere would be black.

Your were close by trying to invert the dist, but the easy answer here was to invert it at the color's level by letting it range *from 255* instead of *to 255*. That's why I wrote it `255 - d`. Then, the further from the center, the closer to zero.

Have fun!

Comment: Brilliant! So good! Yes this it the logic! Thank you so much to explain it to me!